# Python - Global variable modified prior to multiprocessing call is passed as original state

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In Python 3.5 on Windows, I am attempting to design some multiprocessing code which requires some pre-processed variables to be available to the function that is applied to the input.
To make these variables available, I am treating them as global variables.

While this works in a non-parallel approach, using `multiprocessing.Pool` shows behavior that would occur if the global had never been modified from its initialization.

Consider the following snippet:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

testlist = []


def f(x):
    return x*x + testlist[0]


def main():
    global testlist
    input_iter = range(10)
    testlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for i in input_iter:
        print(f(i))
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        for i in pool.imap_unordered(f, input_iter):
            print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The function `f(x)` simply squares the input, and adds an element from the global variable `testlist`.  `testlist` is defined globally first as an empty list, and is then modified to contain the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` in the `main()` function.

Running this code will produce the desired output for the simple `for` loop, but the multiprocessing loop will throw an `IndexError`: to the `Pool` workers, the `testlist` variable has not been modified to contain values and is still an empty list.

```
1
2
5
10
17
26
37
50
65
82
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "progresstest.py", line 7, in f
    return x*x + testlist[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "progresstest.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "progresstest.py", line 17, in main
    for i in pool.imap_unordered(f, input_iter):
  File "\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 695, in next
    raise value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The global variable is modified prior to any creation of the `Pool` workers, and the simple loop shows that this assignment worked: no `IndexError` is thrown in the `for` loop.  I understand that state cannot be shared between processes, but this variable is defined prior to the parallel execution and does not change.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: If I put the code you've posted here in a file and run it with Python 3, it works exactly as expected; is it possible that, in simplifying your code to post the question, you also removed the bit that actually causes the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're on Windows. Multiprocessing doesn't work the way you think it does, and global variables are not a safe way to share data between processes.

Comment: @HaldeanBrown this is Python 3.5.3, and I have edited the question to reflect this.  I am running the script exactly as it appears in the first snippet (in a new conda environment containing only python 3.5), and am receiving the IndexError as shown.  I would be happy to learn that the issue is with my system and not the code, but I'm still facing the issue on my end.  Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @user2357112 you're correct in that I'm developing on Windows.  In trying the example code in a Linux environment, I've found that it works without issue.  I'm curious as to why.  The reason I am using global variables here is because I need a solution that both allows me to update a progress indicator (imap_unordered in a loop), and pass multiple arguments to the function (starmap).  Maybe there is a better solution for this case, but that sounds like another question.

Comment: If you want to pass the function multiple arguments, have it take a tuple instead and pass it a tuple of arguments.

Comment: @Librarian You cannot pass multiple arguments in a mapping, but you *can* pass a `list` or `tuple`, which works just as well. :-) And if some of the arguments are always the same, check out `functools.partial`.

Comment: @RolandSmith thanks, this has improved my code quality quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On UNIX-like operating systems, `multiprocessing` (by default) uses the `fork` system call in creating the `Pool` to make one or more *exact copies* of the master process.

On ms-windows, there is no `fork` system call, so `multiprocessing` works different. It starts a new Python process that *imports* the original program as a module. In this case, `main()` is not called, so your global isn't updated.

Comment: This explains the difference in behavior I was seeing, thank you.  In my specific case, it looks like I can avoid this behavior by passing the needed variables to the parallel function with `pool.starmap` instead of `pool.imap_unordered`, avoiding global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the values you want to pass in tuples (as Roland suggests) or in a list which may offer more flexible handling. Here is an example of multiprocessing with a nested list:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
from time import sleep
def foo(transptbox):
    [myvalues,a] = transptbox
    for j in myvalues:
        val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 = j
    a = a*a + val1   # stands for your process with iterable a and value 1
    sleep(0.1) # using sleep to simulate processing time long enough to activate multiprocessing
    print(f"Process-ID {os.getpid()}:{a} : {val1} {val2} {val3} {val4} {val5}") # just to show values are available
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    values_to_be_sent =  [[1,2,3,4,5]]
    input_iter = range(10)
    tbox =[[0 for y in range(2)]for x in range(len(input_iter))]
    for x in range(len(input_iter)):
        tbox[x] = [values_to_be_sent, input_iter[x]]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 3)
    result = list(pool.map(foo, tbox))
    print(result)
```

The output is the result you wanted to have:

```
C:\Users\757\PycharmProjects\exu\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/757/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_9.py
Process-ID 3476:1 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 4416:5 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 5568:2 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 3476:10 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 4416:17 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 5568:26 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 3476:37 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 5568:50 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 4416:65 : 1 2 3 4 5
Process-ID 3476:82 : 1 2 3 4 5
[1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37, 50, 65, 82]

Process finished with exit code 0
```